# What is a REBOL struct! datatype?

Tags: rebol

What is a struct! datatype in REBOL and how does it work?

Comment: Did you mean the 'C' datatype struct ?

Comment: Why is everyone assuming C/C++? The tag clearly says REBOL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In rebol, struct! is a data type used to approximate struct in the C languages. It also is used in argument specification. A good description of what it is and how to use it is at:

http://www.rebol.com/docs/library.html#struct